# Scraping data off thetrainline.com for tickets and fares

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hello fellow programmers. I am trying to run a python code to scrape off information from thetrainline.com.
I recently started programming and i can't seem to figure out how to extract the data from the post request. Please see below for the information.

The following is my code for now :

```
postURL = 'https://www.thetrainline.com/buytickets/'
predata = {'OriginStation':'Stockport',
'DestinationStation':'Birmingham New Street',
'RouteRestriction':'NULL',
'ViaAvoidStation':'',
'journeyTypeGroup':'return',
'outwardDate':'14-Apr-17',
'OutwardLeaveAfterOrBefore':'A',
'OutwardHour':'15',
'OutwardMinute':'15',
'returnDate':'16-Apr-17',
'InwardLeaveAfterOrBefore':'A',
'ReturnHour':'9',
'ReturnMinute':'0',
'AdultsTravelling':'1',
'ChildrenTravelling':'0',
'railCardsType_0':'YNG',
'railCardNumber_0':'1',
'ExtendedSearch':'Get times & tickets'}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
import requests
postform=requests.post(postURL,headers=headers, data=predata)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(postform.content,'html.parser')
table=soup.find(id='timetable')
```

If i run the command "table" in the Shell , I get the following:

```
>>> table
<form action="combinedmatrix.aspx" class="form matrix matrix-search-outdep matrix-search-returndep" data-defaults='{"adultPassengers":1,"canChangeJourney":true,"canPreselectTicket":true,"childPassengers":0,"destinationName":"Birmingham New Street","fullJourneys":[{"cheapestTickets":[{"label":"Cheapest Standard Single","tickets":[{"code":"MBS","departureTime":"15:16","groupIdentifier":"cheapest","isCheapest":true,"journeyId":1,"price":"9.30","value":"{\"ArrivalStationCode\":\"BHM\",\"DepartureStationCode\":\"SPT\",\"Id\":208,\"JourneyArrivalDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492183980000+0100)\\\/\",\"JourneyDepartureDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492179360000+0100)\\\/\",\"Price\":9.3,\"PriceInPounds\":\"Â£9.30\",\"Type\":2}"},{"code":"MBS","departureTime":"15:36","groupIdentifier":"cheapest","isCheapest":true,"journeyId":2,"price":"9.30","value":"{\"ArrivalStationCode\":\"BHM\",\"DepartureStationCode\":\"SPT\",\"Id\":208,\"JourneyArrivalDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492185480000+0100)\\\/\",\"JourneyDepartureDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492180560000+0100)\\\/\",\"Price\":9.3,\"PriceInPounds\":\"Â£9.30\",\"Type\":2}"},{"code":"SVS","departureTime":"15:40","groupIdentifier":"cheapest","journeyId":3,"price":"23.85","value":"{\"ArrivalStationCode\":\"BHM\",\"DepartureStationCode\":\"SPT\",\"Id\":253,\"JourneyArrivalDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492186680000+0100)\\\/\",\"JourneyDepartureDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492180800000+0100)\\\/\",\"Price\":23.85,\"PriceInPounds\":\"Â£23.85\",\"Type\":2}"},{"code":"MBS","departureTime":"16:16","groupIdentifier":"cheapest","isCheapest":true,"journeyId":4,"price":"9.30","value":"{\"ArrivalStationCode\":\"BHM\",\"DepartureStationCode\":\"SPT\",\"Id\":208,\"JourneyArrivalDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492187580000+0100)\\\/\",\"JourneyDepartureDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492182960000+0100)\\\/\",\"Price\":9.3,\"PriceInPounds\":\"Â£9.30\",\"Type\":2}"}],"ticketsType":"S"},{"label":"Cheapest First Class Single","tickets":[{"code":"MBF","departureTime":"15:16","groupIdentifier":"cheapest","journeyId":1,"price":"24.30","value":"{\"ArrivalStationCode\":\"BHM\",\"DepartureStationCode\":\"SPT\",\"Id\":210,\"JourneyArrivalDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492183980000+0100)\\\/\",\"JourneyDepartureDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492179360000+0100)\\\/\",\"Price\":24.3,\"PriceInPounds\":\"Â£24.30\",\"Type\":2}"},{"code":"MBF","departureTime":"15:36","groupIdentifier":"cheapest","journeyId":2,"price":"24.30","value":"{\"ArrivalStationCode\":\"BHM\",\"DepartureStationCode\":\"SPT\",\"Id\":210,\"JourneyArrivalDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492185480000+0100)\\\/\",\"JourneyDepartureDate\":\"\\\/Date(1492180560000+0100)\\\/\",\"Price\":24.3,\"PriceInPounds\":\"Â£24.30\",\"Type\":2}"},
...
```

How would you recommend getting the dataset from the POST request ?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

Comment: Isn't the data you want inside the `data-defaults` attribute? You can just parse that json.

Comment: What data you actually need ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/tVPxQn96 I formatted out your JSON a little better so it might make a bit more sense as to how you should access it

Comment: I needed the data-defaults to be able to strip only the tickets out and the prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [8]: import json

In [9]: json.loads(table.get('data-defaults'))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the job. Got the info.. now working more on it